# Is it possible to derive from System.String?

Tags: c#, inheritance, base-class

I am deriving a class from `String`, but it won't allow me to inherit from that class. What do I need to do if I want to inherit like this?

```
public class a : string
{ 
  //class definition
}
```

Comment: You can't, `string` is a sealed class. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The short answer is as Maarten says... the question is must you inherit string? Will a string extension do?... I suspect a string extension method will serve your purpose https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: what is your reasoning for wanting to derive from String? (which is not possible to do anyway as it is a sealed class)

Comment: No particular reason for doing like this. i was just checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot inherit from `String` because it is [sealed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx). If you have to extend the provided functionality, you have two options:

- Write a wrapper class around `String` and implement the methods yourself.
- Use [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit from `string` class as it is `sealed`.
For any additional behavior to the `string` class consider creating extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :

You can't derive from basic type.

Long answer :

You can't because the `String` class is maked as sealed, preventing inheritance.

If you want to add methods to the string object, you can use extention methods (more info here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)